# When calling a function in Swift, what does each part mean?

Tags: swift

For example, if I am writing:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

what does `tableView`, `_tableView: UITableView`, and `didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath` each refer to in general terms?

Comment: "if I am calling func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)" You will _never_ call that function. That is a function that Cocoa calls, not you. To know what it means when it is called, read the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview

Comment: Please read [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) book from Apple. It will teach you all about Swift. The section on functions and parameters will cover your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `tableView` is the method name. Then, inside the parentheses are parameters, separated by commas. Each parameter has three parts: the external name, the internal name, and the type. If you want callers to be able to leave off the external name (the name of the parameter used by code *calling* the method), you can replace it with an underscore (_). So, the first parameter has an internal name of `tableView`, with no external name. The part after the colon (:) is the type, the first parameter has a type of `UITableView`. The second parameter has an external name of `didSelectRowAt`, an internal name of `indexPath`, and a type of `IndexPath`.

Comment: This description has some mistakes. The use of `_` for the argument label means the caller does not give any name. If both the "internal" and "external" names (as you call it) are the same, you don't use underscore. You simply leave off the "external" name. And the proper terms are "argument label" ("external") and "parameter name" ("internal").

Comment: Good point, this answer was out of date. I have updated it to be current. Thanks @rmaddy

Answer (score 1):

See The [Swift Language: Functions and Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID463), which says:

> #### Functions and Closures
>
> Use `func` to declare a function. Call a function by following its name with a list of arguments in parentheses. Use `->` to separate the parameter names and types from the function’s return type.
>
> ```
> func greet(person: String, day: String) -> String {
>     return "Hello \(person), today is \(day)."
> }
> greet(person: "Bob", day: "Tuesday")
> ```
>
> By default, functions use their parameter names as labels for their arguments. Write a custom argument label before the parameter name, or write `_` to use no argument label.
>
> ```
> func greet(_ person: String, on day: String) -> String {
>     return "Hello \(person), today is \(day)."
> }
> greet("John", on: "Wednesday")
> ```

So, your question is like this latter example. So, when the OS calls this delegate method, it calls it something like:

```
delegate.tableView(someTableView, didSelectRowAt: someIndexPath)
```

But you never call this method. This is a [`UITableViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate) method that you never call yourself. You implement this method and iOS will call it when the user selects a row from your table.